# AdonisJS unable to return response within a function (SAP HANA)

Tags: node.js, hana, adonis.js

I am using [SAP HANA CLIENT for NodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sap/hana-client) in my AdonisJS project. I am unable to return the response as json from the the function that connects to the database. Here is the code

The controller method `validateInvoice` is first called

```
async validateInvoice({request, response}) {
  const req = request.all()
  const inv_num = req.invoice_num;
  const data = await this.fetchInvStatus(inv_num);
  return response.json({success: true, data: data});
}
```

This in turn calls the `fetchInvStatus` method which actually connects to HANA DB

```
var conn = hana.createConnection();
var conn_params = {
  serverNode: '127.0.0.1:30015',
  uid: 'CUST_USER_ROLE_ADMIN',
  pwd: 'Welcome@1234',
  database: 'DED'
};

conn.connect(conn_params, (err) => {
  if(err) {
    return err;
  }
  conn.exec("Select * FROM SAPDED.YACSF_RRHD where INVOICE_NUMBER = ?", ['BOMT000005'],  (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return err;
    }
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  })
});
```

In the console I'm able to see the result but this result is not being passed to the `validateInvoice` method so that the API could return the response.

The line in the first method `response.json()` is executed even before the data from DB is returned. How can I overcome this problem? I've tried adding `return` statement to `conn.connect` and `conn.exec` but nothing helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return promise in the fetchInvStatus method.

```
function fetchInvStatus() {
 return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
  var conn = hana.createConnection();
  var conn_params = {
    serverNode: '127.0.0.1:30015',
    uid: 'CUST_USER_ROLE_ADMIN',
    pwd: 'Welcome@1234',
    database: 'DED'
  };

  conn.connect(conn_params, (err) => {
    if(err) {
      reject(err);
    }

    conn.exec("Select * FROM SAPDED.YACSF_RRHD where INVOICE_NUMBER = ?", ['BOMT000005'],  (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      console.log(result);
      resolve(result);
     })
    });
   }  
}
```